# May be a trivial question regarding constrained optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Optimization problem is to find $x$>0 which

$min \ \ L=\frac{A\left ( B(\frac{C}{Cx-B}+\frac{1}{x})+2C\log(\frac{B}{x}-C) \right )}{B^3}$

$s.t \  \  x\leq K      $

Rewriting the objective function using Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$

$J = L + \lambda (x-K)$

While solving the optimization problem with Lagrange, I came to the following equations:

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}= \frac{-A}{(Bx-Cx^2)^2}+\lambda$

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \lambda} = x-K$

Consider that $A,B,C,K>0$ and also $B>Cx$.

After solving $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}=0$, I am getting $x=\frac{B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4C\sqrt{A}}}{2C}$. But it may not be less than $K$. How to solve this? Please help.

Comment: Please give explicitly the objective function, the constraint, and the domain of allowed $x$.

Comment: please post the original problem

Comment: Because of the inequality constraint you should apply the KKT-conditions.